# Orfox wont load?

Tags: help, error

My orfox browser won't load. I start orbot, and it loads successfully. But when I try to open orfox, the window just closes. I've uninstalled and reinstalled,as well as restarting my tablet, but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I just installed Orbot and Orfox today for the first time. Using Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0. Orfox closes in about a second every time I open it. This question is the only reference to the problem I could find online except for this bug report from two years ago https://dev.guardianproject.info/issues/5394

Comment: Could you try the new release candidate? See: https://lists.mayfirst.org/pipermail/guardian-dev/2017-August/005306.html

Comment: What hard- and software do you use?